# In Qt c++, QLabel::setText does not work ,but other fun can work

Tags: qt, c++11

I wanted to display the specified content in the label (Client::saveData, a static variable),but I couldn't do it anyway. QMessageBox::information works, and qDebug() outputs the correct content, but it just doesn't show up on the label.

```
//network.h 
public:
    static QByteArray saveData;

//network.cpp
QByteArray Client::saveData = "TEST";

void S8524Widget::setTandHLabel()
{
    QString tempdata(Client::saveData.left(2));
    ui->tempText->setText(tempdata);
}
```

Client::saveData prints correctly. If I put settext in the constructor, it works fine, but I need it to update the text dynamically. In this function, even `setText (“Tempdata”)` doesn't work. If you save `Ui-> tempText` as a variable, calling setText from the mainwindow won't work either.I tried update() and repaint() , and it still didn't work. And there's no other code that controls this label.

I created a new project and tried to replicate it, but it was successfully implemented in this project.

```
//network.h
public:
    static QByteArray saveData;

//network.cpp
QByteArray udpNetwork::saveData = "TEST";

//mainwoindow.cpp
void MainWindow::setdata()
{
    ui->label->setText(QString(udpNetwork::saveData.right(2)));
}
```

The principle was not understood, but the problem was solved: use SIGNAL/SLOT in my timer connect() instead &. Because I need to update "save data" dynamically, I write a timer. I can't describe how I felt when I found the solution.

Like this:

```
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(setTandHLabel()));
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle was not understood, but the problem was solved:use SIGNAL/SLOT in my timer connect() instead &.I can't describe how I felt when I found the solution.

Comment: Hi,  I am glad that you solved this for yourself!  Could you please edit your answer to include modified code that works?  That way other stack overflow users can know what to do. 

Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow